# How to switch from LTS to Weekly release for Jenkins in Windows?

Tags: jenkins

Currently have a Jenkins stable/LTS instance running on Windows Server 2008 R2 which I would like to switch to weekly release. Is there anyway I could edit some config files to have it switch from LTS to Weekly release without a complete reinstallation?

Comment: Isn't W2K8R2 out of support? There is nothing special about the LTS, other than it's more stable and major changes come only on a majot cahnge, not weekly. Nevertheless, you should be able to stop your instance and swap out the binary amd atart a higher binary ver. I have not tried it, so caveat emptor, makes sure you have working backups and try it on a non-prod or backup instance.

Answer (score 2):

Found the quick way of doing this:

Go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced tab.

Change the update Site URL to https://updates.jenkins.io/current/update-center.json (note the "current" part in URL).

Now go back to Updates -> Check Now and you should see a new version is available for download (obviously if newest in weekly is higher than the LTS release, which is almost always the case).

Switching back should be as easy as change the "current" to "stable" in URL, however you might need to wait until the LTS version number surpass the weekly version number.

Comment: Well, that's clever! Never occurred to me the plugins update center was also applicable to the core update, though now that's totally obvious. Is that actually documented or was it discovered?

Comment: I didn't find any documentation about it, but looking through the Jenkins update site URLs seems to indicate this could work (and it indeed did when I tried it)